# How to use sub query in INNER JOIN ON condition in zf2..?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have to implement a condition in sql query where i need to use sub query in INNER JOIN ON condition as follows :

```
$select = new Select('booking');
        $select->columns(array('*', new Expression("service_provider.first_name as sp_first_name, service_provider.last_name as sp_last_name,
        invoice.status_id AS invoice_status,payment_history.currency as currency,CASE invoice.status_id WHEN 0 THEN 'Unpaid' WHEN 1 THEN 'Paid' WHEN 2 THEN 'Partially Paid' END AS PaymentStatus")));
        $select->join('booking_suggestion_history', 'booking_suggestion_history.booking_id = booking.id AND booking_suggestion_history.id = (SELECT id FROM booking_suggestion_history WHERE booking_id = booking.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)', 'inner');
        $select->join('users', 'users.id = booking.user_id', array('first_name', 'last_name'), 'left');
        $select->join(array('service_provider' => 'users'), 'service_provider.id = booking.service_provider_id', array(), 'left');
        $select->join('service_provider_service', 'service_provider_service.id = booking.service_provider_service_id', array('duration', 'price'), 'left');
        $select->join('service_category', 'service_category.id = service_provider_service.service_id', array('category_name'), 'left');
        $select->join('invoice', 'invoice.id = booking.invoice_id', array('invoice_total', 'site_commision'), 'inner');
        $select->join('invoice_details', 'invoice_details.invoice_id = invoice.id', array('sale_item_details'), 'inner');
        $select->join('payment_history', 'payment_history.invoice_id = invoice.id', array(), 'inner');
        $select->join('lookup_status', 'lookup_status.status_id = booking.status_id', array('status'), 'left');
```

query generating through these conditions (got through str_replace('"', '', $select->getSqlString());) is working fine in sql but zf2 throwing error :

```
Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`id` `FROM` `booking_suggestion_history` `WHERE` `booking_id` = `booking`.`id` `' at line 2)
```

Please help..!!

Comment: How come your `$select->join('booking_suggestion_history....` join statement does not have the 3rd parameter as an array of columns but instead has 'inner' which should be the 4th parameter. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes i have checked that and corrected the code but still its not working..!!

Comment: Can you please add the generated raw SQL string in the question too. You said its working fine in sql - its mysql right?